# Disabled button until all fields have been entered in xslt using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt

I am having difficulty trying to disable submit button for form until all fields have values in xslt using javascript.

I am using a xml file and transforming it to html using xslt. The code below shows what I am trying to do.

Xslt file

```
 <input id="save_choice" type="submit" value="Save Choice" />
```

The error says "can't find variable" in line 1

```
(function() {
$('form > input').keyup(function() {     !can't find variable

    var empty = false;
    $('form > input').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            empty = true;
        }
    });

    if (empty) {
        $('#save_choice').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
        $('#save_choice').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

})()

Can you please advice? thank you

---

***Update***
Below is full xslt file and js file I am working with. thank you for any help in advance

```
  <head><script src="validation.js" type="text/javascript"/>


  </head>

  <body>
<h1>Give As You Earn</h1>

  <xsl:for-each select="data/options">

    <fieldset>
  <form name="form1" action="#">
      <label><xsl:value-of select="selectionText" /></label>
      <input type="text" name="{@inputName}" value="{@currentValue}" min="{@minimum}" max="{@maximum}" step="{@increment}"/>
      <span><xsl:value-of select="@suffix" /></span>
      <br/>
      <label>Please tell us which charity you wish to donate to</label>
      <input type="text" name="charity"></input>
      <br/>
      <input id="save_choice" type="submit" value="Save Choice" />
      <button><a href="#" target="_blank">Save Choice</a></button> 
  </form>
          </fieldset>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

validation.js file

```
(function() {
$('form > input').keyup(function() {

    var empty = false;
    $('form > input').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            empty = true;
        }
    });

    if (empty) {
        $('#save_choice').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
        $('#save_choice').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

})()

Comment: Which library do you use that defines `$`, where is it included? Where have you placed your Javascript code? Consider to use the code snippet feature to add minimal but complete snippets to allow us to reproduce the problem

Comment: I have placed in a separate js file. and it is included in header of xslt.

Comment: A script call in the head during page load does not have access to elements included later in the body, so call your code when the document is ready, e.g. in a DOMContentLoaded event listener or whatever your library provides. Or include the script at the end of the body, after the content it tries to access.